# How to make a software manager always use --no-install-recommends?

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-installation, lubuntu, lxqt

Trying to install kwin in Lubuntu Lxqt I found it was to be installed in Discover, Muon or Apper with 176 dependencies, practically the whole Plasma desktop.

Then I found about `sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends` which provided the right solution.

Can I make one of the software managers use that by default? Or does any of them have a setting to enable the option?

Comment: See `apt-config dump | grep Recommends` to expose the setting, and see `man apt-config` for how to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muon has such a setting: click `Settings` in the menu-bar, then chose `Configure Muon Package Manager`

[image]

and uncheck the checkbox `Treat recommended packages as dependencies`.